# Reading PHP man pages in Vim

Tags: php, vim, manpage

I have setup the ability to read the PHP manual via pman as described here:
http://bjori.blogspot.com/2010/01/unix-manual-pages-for-php-functions.html

In my `.vimrc` file I have added the following so I can press `K` to read the man page in a new split window.

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim
nnoremap K :Man <cword><cr>
```

This works perfectly, sometimes. Certain functions show the man pages just as you would expect. Others, I get the error "Cannot find a 'method_exists'.", for example. First, I wondered if the man pages were out of date but it doesn't seem as they are.

If I run `pman method_exists` from the terminal, I see the expected man page.

Does anyone have any idea why only some of the man pages appear correctly inside of Vim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that when pressing `K` would show man pages for some keywords only because those keywords also had man pages associated. I didn't inspect the man page close enough to notice that it wasn't for the PHP keyword.

I had to specify the man path before this would work properly. I have updated the lines in my `~/.vimrc` to the following:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/man.vim
nnoremap K :Man --manpath=/usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/pman/ <cword><cr>
```

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: You can do the same thing with `setkeywordprg = /usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/pman` I think

Answer (score 0):

It could be the differentiation between a word and a WORD. See `:help <cword>` versus `<cWORD>`. However, you may not always want a WORD, so you may instead need to resort to first visually selecting the selection keyword and then pressing `K`.

Comment: I will have to read about the differences between `<cword>` and `<cWORD>`. I'm a bit confused though, in both cases, the function is lowercase.

Comment: @jayem it doesn't have to do with lowercase/uppercase, but instead the underscore.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is because of the underscore because the man page for `htmlentities` does not function properly either.

I have also tried `<cWORD>` instead of `<cword>` with no difference.

Lastly, selecting the word in visual mode, then using `K` doesn't work either.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if some of the man pages are shown as expected because the keyword exists in other man pages (example: `date`). When I perform `:Man -w date` inside of Vim, I get `/usr/share/man/man1/date.1.gz` where as with `pman` it is `/usr/share/doc/php5-common/PEAR/pman/man3/date.3.gz`.